# Что такое "княжеское строительство"?

Tags: значение-слов

[В Новгороде **княжеское строительство** не велось, церкви сооружались на средства горожан, предназначались для повседневной службы, поэтому были сравнительно невелики и просты в убранстве. Новгородские церкви были приземисты, имели мощные стены. Наиболее известны среди них Георгиевский собор Юрьева монастыря (трехкупольный), церковь Спаса на Нередице, Петра и Павла на Синичьей горе, Параскевы Пятницы на Ярославовом дворище.](http://www.1543.ru/school/books/Kacva_History_abitur/chap11.htm)

Не гуглится, из контекстов не вполне ясно!

У меня:

> Лучшее, что можно сделать здесь, – мысленно воскресить свои пешие
>   прогулки по старым русским городам и припомнить наши «белокаменные»
>   храмы, которые возводятся примерно в то же самое время в Господине
>   Великом Новгороде, Пскове, Суздале. И здесь и там – перед нами будут
>   **примеры так называемого княжеского строительства**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- "Припомнить наши **белокаменные** храмы" — кавычки в слове "белокаменные" не нужны.

[БЕЛОКА́МЕННЫЙ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/96094/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) -ая, -ое. *Нар.-поэт.* Сделанный, построенный из белого камня. *Белокаменные стены, палаты. Белокаменный кремль. Москва белокаменная.*

Це́рковь Покрова́ на Нерли́ — белокаменный храм во Владимирской области; Успе́нский собо́р во Влади́мире — выдающийся памятник белокаменного зодчества домонгольской Руси; усадебный белокаменный храм Знамения Пресвятой Богородицы ([Русь белокаменная](https://books.google.ee/books?id=knI3DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC&source=bl&ots=zvheYY0Q4I&sig=ACfU3U3xaz4XjMgbWVpXX3exXzDfXCOCyQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-wJTg3MDjAhXDDOwKHZnnDak4ChDoATADegQIBRAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC&f=false)).

- Все правильно — есть такой термин "княжеское строительство".

Новгородское восстание 1136 г. приостановило княжеское строительство в Новгороде и открыло дорогу боярскому ([История СССР с древнейших времен до наших дней. Т. 1](https://books.google.ee/books?id=ekksDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA674&lpg=PA674&dq=%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=Ev27Czp2hc&sig=ACfU3U1MGucM14mWphNQ3b9qN-1cWuMmBw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwia4tSt28DjAhUCU1AKHbEUClgQ6AEwDXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE&f=false)).

Княжеское строительство, можно сказать, прокладывало магистральную линию развития архитектуры этой поры. Кроме князей строили и церковные иерархи ([Архитектура второй половины XI и начала XII века](http://sakai.spbu.ru/portal/pda/ARTH_E409_S09_SPBGU_4/tool/efd9687e-e085-44b4-ace1-b300a480e6a1/print_module.jsf?printModuleId=2621448)).

Вот [здесь](https://%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%20%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0,%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%20XII%20%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0.) еще.

Повышенный спрос на каменное строительство со стороны духовенства и горожан привел к появлению и массовому распространению той максимально простой модификации крестово-купольного храма, которая определила облик архитектуры последней трети XII  века.

Нередица строилась по княжескому заказу. Но на архитектуре здания это никак не отразилось. Если в начале XII  века княжеское строительство задавало тон, то к концу века оно не выделялось из общего типологического и образного ряда, наглядно демонстрируя весьма скромное положение института княжеской власти в общественной жизни города.

Получается, что речь идет о строительстве храмов на княжеские средства (в отличие от строительства на средства духовенства, бояр или горожан).